# Is it safe to store a JWT in client javascript?

Tags: javascript, jwt

Is there anything wrong with storing a JWT in a client side javascript variable? When I search for this all I see are questions regarding cookies vs local storage, etc. I just want to know if its ok to store it in a variable for later use. Would this make my web app any more vulnerable?

Comment: There is no method which can make your web application 100% secure from vulnerable attacks. There are multiple approaches which actually helps out to minimise the effect JWT is also a method to actually reduce the impact by allowing to store the tokens in client instead of credentials. You can store JWT in cookies or localStorage there is not much difference. It just that don't store it right way instead encrypt it and store it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ashvin777. I would suggest encrypting the JWT to make it a JWE.  This way if it does fall into naughty hands there is a level of protection.  This link shows how to create a JWT as a encrypted JWE.  Use this and store this.  You can choose from many types of encryption.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516